# Facing error in building android in Ionic Framework

Tags: ionic-framework

I am having an error when running the command:

```
$ ionic build android
```

[image]

Comment: can anyone help me? i searched but couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install Android SDK and configure your Android_Home correctly ?

See [Here](http://spring.io/guides/gs/android/#android-dev-env) for a detailed, step by step documentation.